# VirtualBox 5.1.28 fails to install on MacOS 10.13 due to KEXT security

Tags: macos, security, virtualbox, high-sierra, kernel-extensions

I have tried to install VirtualBox 5.1.28 to macOS high sierra but it fails every time with the following screen:
[image: Virtual Box Installation Failure]

After some looking around I found [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300510/virtualbox-5-1-8-installation-didnt-install-kernel-extensions-how-do-i-fix-thi) and I did indeed see that it was blocking VirtualBox from installing.

[image: Security and Privacy settings]

After clicking allow and then trying to run the VirtualBox installer again it just fails again with the same generic error message and the same Security warning reappears in the "Security and Privacy" settings.

I tried to also run the pkg install from the terminal to see if I could get more information about why its failing but it doesnt help.

```
➜  Documents sudo installer -verbose -pkg VirtualBox.pkg -target /
installer: Package name is Oracle VM VirtualBox
installer: Installing at base path /
installer: Preparing for installation….....
installer: Preparing the disk….....
installer: Preparing Oracle VM VirtualBox….....
installer: Waiting for other installations to complete….....
installer: Configuring the installation….....
installer:
#
installer: Writing files….....
#
installer: Writing files….....
#
installer: Optimizing system for installed software….....
#
installer: Running package scripts….....
#
installer: Running package scripts….....
#
installer: Running package scripts….....
#
installer: Running package scripts….....
#
installer: Running package scripts….....
#
installer: Running package scripts….....
installer: Validating packages….....
#
installer: The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)
```

The VirtualBox application does appear to install and it can be launched however nothing functions.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Managed to solve it.

- Eject the VirtualBox image from: Finder > Devices

  [image: Remove VirtualBox device]
- Now allow the exception in: System Preferences > Security & Privacy

  [image: Security & Privacy]
- Finally but not least click `Allow` button so that way the developer with the name "Oracle America, Inc" will be accepted and the installer using that certificate will run just fine (basically this installer is signed using "Oracle America, Inc" certificate so we are required to enable it use on our machine first)
- Then try to install from the .dmg again so that it remounts the device.

Now its working fine for me.

Comment: Awesome. Good thing to know.

Comment: I'm using MacOS 10.13.1 (High Sierra), and I didn't see the option to "Allow". I followed the steps at this link: http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/27/allow-apps-from-anywhere-macos-gatekeeper/ (basically, I ran `sudo spctl --master-disable`) and the option appeared. However, the option didn't work - Each time I ran the installer, I got an "Allow" option. The "Allow" wasn't being remembered for some reason...

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm in High Sierra 10.13.2 and Vbox 5.2.6

Comment: I had issues with this not allowing me to click "Allow" when I first tried it. A full reboot of the Mac fixed it up and then the install was fine.

Comment: One needs to reboot to safe mode (holding shift on reboort) and allow button works there.

Comment: I had the same failure running `brew cask install virtualbox`. Following the same steps in this answer, running `brew cask install virtualbox` again succeeded. Thank you!

Comment: This helped me to install Virtualbox on Mojave https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/51112

Comment: If you don't have "Allow" button try to use another version of VirtualBox. In my case I didn't see button with versions 4.3.40, 5.1.38, but saw with 6.1.26.

Answer (score 8):

For those still struggling with this issue:

**IF YOU ARE CONNECTING VIA REMOTE DESKTOP OR SCREEN SHARING** or have any other mouse emulation running: It is not possible to actually click the `Allow` button in this mode!!

So do the following:

1. Run the installer until the location prompt
2. open System Preferences
3. Take a screenshot (`CMD+SHIFT+3`)
4. Open the screenshot with Preview, and select from top left to the button, and note down the coordinates
5. Then open `Script Editor`, and run the following line of code:

   `tell application "System Events" to click at {890, 460}`

   Use the coordinates from step 4. and make sure you don't move the Preferences window, and that no other window is overlaying the button. (It could be you need to give Script Editor Accessibility permission, but it will prompt you)

Now the button is actually clicked, and you can allow "Oracle America, Inc." to install. You might be prompted for a reboot. Then run the installer again and everything should work as expected!

Comment: I just ran into this the other day with Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65). I was VNC-ing into my local server and couldn't press the "Allow" button, I had to connect a Bluetooth keyboard or mouse to it in order for it to be allowed.

Comment: Wow, what an annoying bug/feature, thanks for saving me continuing to bang my head against the wall trying to install VirtualBox remotely . . . .

Comment: I can't believe this worked haha. I'm not on remote desktop, so I wonder what's triggering this.

Answer (score 6):

The answer at the following link worked for me. It required running the script provided by `dstroot`, approving the kext in `Security & Privacy` and then installing with `brew cask reinstall --force virtualbox --verbose --debug`. https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/39369

Comment: This solved my problem!

Answer (score 5):

If the GUI solution does not work, reboot in Recovery mode and enter `spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963`, then reboot in normal mode and install should be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much, Liviu Ionescu. The command line solution you provided, after having changed Security Preferences, was the only solution that worked for me!

Comment: This doesn't work for my, throws error in both normal and safe mode

Comment: @TheNano, what macOS version do you use? And what errors did you see?

Answer (score 5):

For some reason when I clicked "allow" it felt as if the button "did nothing" but then when I tried it a third time the button "took" (after which point it always worked).  Weird.

More ideas:

reboot into safe mode, try the allow button there

command [line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/300518/25085): `sudo spctl --master-disable`

This is a community wiki feel free to add some more ideas here.

Comment: Please, which button are you talking of?

Comment: The "allow" button in the Security and Privacy preference pane

Comment: It looks like you may have to wait a period of time with the preference pane displayed before the "allow" button actually functions.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a quick note in one of the messages here or in another thread and it was the critical piece I was missing.

When I had the Security & Privacy dialog open, the Apply button visible and clicking on the button and there was no apparent action. The prompt still remained. I needed to **WAIT longer** before trying the Apply. I found I waited 20 minutes until the button actually worked (the prompt went away).

Comment: This worked for me too; I waited about 5 min and then I could press the Allow button